# How to Retrieve a sub-object from an object where the ID of the sub-object is known

Tags: javascript

I have an object called Suppliers where the id is always unique as follows:

```
var suppliers = {
    Supplier1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Supplier1',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier1'
    },
    Supplier2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Supplier2',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier2'
    },
    Supplier3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Supplier3',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier3'
   }
}
```

How can I return the sub-object (e.g return suppliers.Supplier1) when all I know is the id of the sub object? I tried to use .filter, but that only seems to work on arrays:

```
function findById(source, id) {
    return source.filter(function (obj) {
        return +obj.id === +id;
    })[0];
}

var supplierarray = findById(suppliers, myKnownID);
return supplierarray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the `object` using `for-in` loop, you tried to use `.filter` which is for array.

So you can change `findById` definition to below

```
var suppliers = {
    Supplier1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Supplier1',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier1'
    },
    Supplier2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Supplier2',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier2'
    },
    Supplier3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Supplier3',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier3'
   }
}
// Should return single object not array, as id is unique as OP said 
function findById(source, id) {
   for(var key in source){
     if(source[key].id === id){
       return source[key];
     }
   }
  return null;
}

findById(suppliers,3);// {id: 3, name: "Supplier3", SVGTemplate: "svg-supplier3"}
```

Comment: Thanks JagsSparrow, this has returned the object exactly as if I had written return suppliers.Supplier1 for an id of 1, meaning I don't have to hard-code each supplier for a switch statement. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(suppliers).map(key => suppliers[key]).find(({id}) => id === someId);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any key in its child objects.

```
 Object.prototype.findBy = function(propName, propVal){

    for( var i in this ){

         if( this[i][ propName ] == propVal ){
            return this[i];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
};

var suppliers = {
    Supplier1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Supplier1',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier1'
    },
    Supplier2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Supplier2',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier2'
    },
    Supplier3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Supplier3',
        SVGTemplate: 'svg-supplier3'
   }
}

console.log(suppliers.findBy("id",1));
```

Here i've added function inside prototype of root Object.